# spin down hdd with no assigned letter

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I've 3 hdd and a ssd on my pc.

- ssd C: contains windows
- hdd D: is used for daily stuff (intalling programs too heavy for my small sdd and holding documents)
- hdd E: is used for rarely accessed files
- hdd with no letter has ubuntu (lets call it U)

I'd like to spin down the last 2. Specially E because it makes a lot of noise (according to smart it's not failing. It's a constant, a bit loud humming)

I managed to spin them down with [revosleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/), but they keep spinning up after a while.

According to process monitor what's waking up E: is either system or explorer, so I feel that trying to get rid of the processes waking it up a dead end.
I couldn't see what's waking up U because since it has no letter I don't know how to identify what processes are accessing it, though since it has no letter there shouldn't be any.

I gave up about using revosleep and just set up the energy options to spin down my disks after 5 minutes, which I know is a bad idea but you won't believe just how loud E and U together sound. It's unbearable at night without the street's sound to cover it.

However U never spins down. I can tell because if I manually spin it down with revosleep it gets a lot quieter.
The point of the question is (sorry for the long intro) why doesn't windows spin down U? Since it has no asigned letter windows should have no reason to access it and it should spin down at least after the set 5 minutes and never wake up until I restart, right?

Revosleep claimed that E: was slave of U, but I disregarded that as an error it because as far as I know SATA drives don't have master-slave relationship like IDE drives. But maybe I'm wrong so I thought it was worth mentioning

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCZLt.png]

Comment: You don't need drive letters to access a drive. Windows uses this under the hood `"\\?\Volume{GUID}\"`. You can mount them as directories on another drive etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the "U" drive offline by right clicking on the windows start button and chosing Disk Management. Right click on the "U" drive and opt to take it offline. Windows shouldnt mess with it anymore.

You can obviously do the same thing for the E drive and only bring it online the few times you use it.

Comment: I had tried disabling it on devices administrator, but for some reason it always read "it's uninstalling" and was never done with it even after rebooting. Plus it kept spinning. I didn't know you could disconnect it from disk management. It asked me to rebook twice to disconect it so it may not be good for E since I'd have to reboot twice every time I want to turn it off after using it, but it's certainly a solution for U. I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, if Windows 10 Search allows indexing of those rarely-used drives, that could be opening them. It's easy to [stop Windows Search Index rebuild](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/simple-ways-to-increase-your-computers-performace-turn-off-indexing-on-your-local-drives/) on specific drives:

- Right-click a drive in Explorer.
- Select *Properties*.
- On the *General* tab, uncheck *Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed...* Note that File Properties may still be indexed (though that should not wake the drive) unless you turn of Indexing completely.

Also, Disk Optimization might do so. You can [turn off optimization of specific drives.](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/30/how-to-disable-automatic-drive-optimization-in-windows-10/)

- Right-click a drive in Explorer.
- Select *Properties*.
- On the *Tools* tab, select *Optimize*.
- Click the *Change settings* button.
- Click the *Drives* button *Choose*.
- Uncheck any drive that should not be regularly optimized.

Another process that might wake drives is antimalware scanning, for which you can create an exception.

Comment: thanks for answering. 
I had already disabled indexing on E, but I hadn't disabled optimization. It may explain why I still see explorer accessing it on process monitor. It says it never ran, but surely checking to see if it needs optimization wakes it up. I had also added an execption on avira and I don't see it accessing E on process monitor. Though how does this affect the ubuntu drive? Win shouldn't be indexing an ext4 drive