# hdd won't spin down even with sata port disabled

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I had already briefly mentioned this drive on question about a different drive ([spin down hdd with no assigned letter](https://superuser.com/questions/1564572/spin-down-hdd-with-no-assigned-letter)) but now it's a different problem.

The hdd in question is a drive that I use only for rarely accessed data. I didn't want to spin it down in a way that would make it too difficult to access the data, but I got curious and started trying solutions that do not meet that criteria. Just to see if I could actually get it to spin down (also because it's annoying to hear it spin up several times a day). So far with no luck.

This is what I already tried

- Disabled indexation
- Disabled optimization

At this point I could spin down the drive through [revosleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/) or window's energy configuration. But it would spin up again after a while, even though process monitor showed no processes on that drive.

- Disabled the disk on device manager
- Disconnect the disk on disks manager

The latest had worked for my ubuntu drive, but for some reason my rarely accessed data drive did not spin down at all after this. Revosleep couldn't see it (so no chance to manually spin it down) and even if I set up window's sleep timer at 1 minute it won't spin down.

Now I tried disabling the sata port on my bios, but I'm still hearing my drive buzzing! At this point I'm afraid of disconnecting it physically from the power unit, because if it spins up I'll have to call an exorcist.

Comment: Current OS that you are trying to do this?

Comment: The OS tells the drive to power down. It also tells the drive to power up, whenever it needs to access it. That would be ANY time the disks / drives are being enumerated. Such as when you open or save a file and are presented with a file explorer dialogue. Using the drive consists of more than just specifically reading / writing a file to it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the SATA standard specifies that you can implement hot plug support, I believe that relates more to the data cables.  I've certainly seen PSUs (power supply units) that provide SATA power cables with no real way to control which drive would become deprived of power.  Although, servers may have drive bays where the SATA power is built into the bay, and I suspect that the entire bay might get turned off when using the "hot plug" support specified by the SATA standard.  So, focusing on telling the motherboard to turn off the power might be more helpful, depending on what computer it is in.

Beyond that, you're asking about a device's behavior when it is only given power.  If you don't have a data cable affecting it, then you won't be able to use software to send data to it.  There might not be any way to affect how the device reacts without a data cable going to it.  But if there is such a way...

such details likely depend greatly on which drive model you are using.  I suspect this question has no possible answer until modified to add details like the manufacturer and make/model of the drive in question.

That said, older drives (MFM/RLL) drives were supposed to be parked before being shut off, or there could be a "hard drive crash" where lost electrical power caused a piece to fall onto a hard drive platter while the platter was still spinning, causing physical damage leading to a massive inability to work well on all affected sectors.  Since then, IDE drives started to support auto-park, so that even in the middle of a write they should be able to turn off in a non-damaging way.  For that reason, I wouldn't be too worried about removing a power plug from a running drive, especially one using the even-newer SATA standard.  Granted, it might not be a super-recommended practice to do regularly for long-term health of the drive, and I suppose there is some risk of sparking when physically removing electric equipment, but such risk can be quite low and I wouldn't be too prone to worry about doing it once for some reason, as long as I've taken appropriate cautions (like ensuring that what I value even more, the data, has a suitable backup).